# Drupal Hook_Block_View perform action on button click

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, hook

I am learning drupal and am trying to add some extra features to a module I've made following a tutorial

I have one block 'History' which shows the last x pages you've viewed.

Now I've made a second block with a button 'clear history', but I can't figure out how to make the set_value('trails_block_history','0') happen when my button is clicked (which would clear my history in the database)

anybody who can help me out here?

My blocks:

```
    function trails_block_info() {
  $blocks['history'] = array(
    'info' => t('History'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  $blocks['clearHist'] = array(
    'info' => t('Clear history'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

hook block save:

```
function trails_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
  variable_set('trails_block_num', $edit['trails_block_num']);
  variable_set('trails_block_granularity',$edit['trails_block_granularity']);
}
```

and the problem:

```
function trails_block_view($delta = '') {    
...
case 'clearHist' :
      {
        $block['subject'] = 'Clear History';
        $block['content'] = '<button>clear history</button>';
      } break;  
...
```

Still a student and reaaally new to this (started the module-coding this morning) so sorry if this seems like a stupid question (which it most probably is) but I just can't find it..

Have made another extra feature on the module allready, so I want this one to work as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Forms API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to create a form with submit button. Then clear your history when form is submitted. More info [here](http://drupal.org/node/37775) and some example code [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example.module/group/form_example/7)

Comment: thank you very much!

I think I will continue with my tutorial first.. the Form API is only 2 chapters away.